# Try/Exception flow control

Tags: python-3.x

Codes:

```
def get_wordlen():
   wordfamily_lst = []
   while True:
      try:
        word_len = int(input('\nPlease enter length of the word you wish to guess: '))
        input_File = open('dic.txt', 'r').read().split()
        for word in input_File:
          if len(word) == word_len:
            wordfamily_lst.append(word)
          else:
            print("Sorry, there's no word of that length")
        continue

      except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a numeric value for word length')
        continue
      return word_len, wordfamily_lst

wordlen, wordfamilylst = get_wordlen()
print(wordlen,wordfamilylst)
```

How can i modify my "else" statement to safeguard against user input of  word length that the txt. file does not contain.  Right now, my codes will display the print statement for EVERY word that doesn't match with the user input of word length.

I'd like just one print statement and loop back to the top of the while loop.

Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `try` block as:

```
    word_len = int(input('\nPlease enter length of the word you wish to guess: '))
    input_File = open('dic.txt', 'r').read().split()
    wordfamily_lst = []
    for word in input_File:
      if len(word) == word_len:
        wordfamily_lst.append(word)
    if not wordfamily_lst:
      print("Sorry, there's no word of that length")
    continue
```

- The `for word in input_File:` will execute for all words in the file
  appending the word to `wordfamily_lst` only if the lengths match.
- Since we are now assigning `wordfamily_lst = []` inside the `while`
  block, the `if not wordfamily_lst:` will make sure the error is
  printed only if the input word is not present in the file.

On a related note, it would be a good idea to move the code to read the file outside the `while True:` block, read all the words in the file into a list once and compare the user input with this new list.

To summarize, this is what I mean:

```
def get_wordlen():
   input_file_words = open('dic.txt', 'r').read().split()
   while True:
      try:
        word_len = int(input('\nPlease enter length of the word you wish to guess: '))
        wordfamily_lst = []
        for word in input_file_words:
          if len(word) == word_len:
            wordfamily_lst.append(word)
        if not wordfamily_lst:
          print("Sorry, there's no word of that length")
        continue

      except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a numeric value for word length')
        continue
      return word_len, wordfamily_lst

wordlen, wordfamilylst = get_wordlen()
print(wordlen,wordfamilylst)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your explanations are very thorough, it's very helpful for someone who just beginning to learn computer science like myself.